# How to swap position of HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have the HTML:

```
<div id="divOne">Hello</div> <div id="divTwo">World</div>
```

Is it possible with CSS/JS/jQuery to swap it around so the contents of `divTwo` appears in the position of `divOne` and vice-versa ? I'm just looking to change the position of each div, so I don't want any solution that involves setting/swapping the HTML of each.

The idea is to let a user customise the order content appears on the page. Is what I'm trying to do a good way of going about that, or is there a better way of achieving it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll be relieved to know it's not hard at all using jQuery.

```
$("#divOne").before($("#divTwo"));
```

Edit: If you're talking about implementing drag-and-drop functionality for ordering the divs, take a look at jQuery UI's sortable plugin... http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: Does this move the elements or copy them?

Comment: @jocull It'll move it, whereas `$("#divOne").before($("#divTwo").clone())` will copy it.

Comment: I guess jQuery really is great and does all things! before() looks like just what I was after - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

http://snipplr.com/view/50142/swap-child-nodes/ has the code to swap 2 elements with each other.

I have also modified the same code so that it also preserves event listeners (`addEventListener`) in the elements that are being swapped and their child nodes.

```
function swapNodes(node1, node2) {
    node2_copy = node2.cloneNode(true);
    node1.parentNode.insertBefore(node2_copy, node1);
    node2.parentNode.insertBefore(node1, node2);
    node2.parentNode.replaceChild(node2, node2_copy);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps by using floats.

```
#divOne {
   float: right;
}

#divTwo {
   float: left;
}
```

YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think my example wasn't that great. In my actual situation there could be 10 or more divs to be ordered anyway the user wants, I don't think floats would be practical for that really.

Comment: @miket2e No worries, it was hard to know if it would work or not without any HTML to go by.